# How to handle multiple pages in gwt application

Tags: gwt

I am working on gwt application I am using "Anchor" for this , I exactly want that without page refresh my content should be change and also browser will update the url

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are asking. Maybe you want [activities and place](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html)

Basically the framework lets you have `Places` which you can navigate to with the `PlaceController`. This does not trigger a full page reload but will change the current view being shown.

In fact the `Place` calls the matching `Activity` which is the "brains" of the page. The activity can then add the `View` to the page. The `View` contains as little logic as possible and is suppose to hold all of the user interface. The `View` should in fact be an interface which a `ViemImplementation` can implement therefore you can have mane Views for the same `Activity` (eg desktop, mobile, tablet).

Answer (score 0):

Activies and Places needs a lot of boilerplate.

If you just want to update the URL you should use the [the GWT History Mechanism](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html).
 CodeExample:

```
public App implements ValueChangeHandler<String>{
    // listen for the History Change Events
    History.addValueChangeHandler(this);

    private void showPanelOne(){
        container.clear();
        container.add(new Panel());
    }

    private void showPanelTwo(){
        container.clear();
        container.add(new Panel());
    }

    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        String token = event.getValue();   
        if (token != null) {
            if (token.contains(Tokens.PANELONE)) {
                showPanelOne()
            } else if (token.contains(Tokens.PANELTWO)) {
                showPanelTwo()
            }
        } else {
            //show default panel or just do nothing?
        }
    }
}  

public class Tokens {
    public final static String PANELONE = "!/panelone";
    public final static String PANELTWO = "!/paneltwo";
}
```

To change the URL just

1)call:

`History.newItem(Tokens.PANELTWO)`

2)use HTML in UI binder:

`<a href="#{Tokens.PANELONE}">Show PanelOne</a>`

This will change the part after the `#` what will look like *http://test.com/#!/panelone*. The `onValueChange` method registers that the URL is updated and handles what happens then, for example show another window.  Hashbang(#!) is used to make the site seo friendly (see [Better SEO with GWT](https://blog.arcbees.com/2015/05/12/better-seo-with-gwt/#making-crawlable) )

An example source code of an seo friendly homepage that updates the URL can you find [here](https://github.com/ArcBees/arcbees-website).

EDIT: seo stuff and example added

Comment: If I dont want to use hash (#) just normal url) then what will be the idea

Comment: Actually I need seo friendly url, not the hash , I did with hash to change the page, but I could'nt find any solution for that :(

Comment: an example on how to use history management and an crawlable, seo friendly page is the arcbees homepage http://www.arcbees.com/#!/expertise

Comment: for an seo friendly url you have to use hashbang #!. take a look here: blog.arcbees.com/2015/05/12/better-seo-with-gwt